# fastest way to locate specific cell in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, indexing, cell

I wondered how to easy access the column index for a specific cell in pandas.

E.g. if i got this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0:['01_CF56_1'],   1:['05_CF41_3'], 2:['06_CF44_2']})
```

i'd like to have a function that gives me

```
f('05_CF41_3') => 1
```

because this value is in the column index 1 (I don't care about the row)

of course the naive way would be to go through all rows and columns and match the cell contents, but i wonder if there is a more elegant solution

Comment: If you need to look up that data, then why don't you just build a simple dictionary as an index? People get so enamored by pandas that they don't think about Python.

Comment: ;) true. it's just so easy to read in the data with pd.read_csv()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the second element of [indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to get the column indices and use it in `where`. Then find the first valid column index using `argmax`:

```
np.argmax(np.where(df == '05_CF41_3', np.indices(df.shape)[1], -1) >= 0)
```

returns `1`.

If the searched for value may occur in multiple columns you could use something like that to get a list of all column numbers where this value occurs:

```
a = np.where(df == '05_CF41_3', np.indices(df.shape)[1], -1)
list(set(a[a>=0]))
```

Comment: Thanks Stef, it works with my toy example, but sadly not with my real data. which is this:

Comment: thanks, i needed to add a modulo because my real data has many rows

Comment: ```def get_fold(test, df):
    return np.argmax(np.where(df == test, np.indices(df.shape)[1], -1) >= 0) % df.shape[1]```